# heroku.com use it as a git repository

Tags: heroku, github

I have a gitHub repository, and I love it. My company is using SalesForce and I am developing an iOS App.

Now I would like to use github, but working with Salesforce who bought heroku.com, I am told to use heroku.com for backend processing.

Is this possible, my impression is that you can do other languages like Java for backend coding, but not for other stuff like ios. Is this the right way or should I convince my manager to buy github access(private hub)?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "backend processing?" Are you talking about server-side computing? Or are you just talking about a place to host your repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to use GitHub for your repository and source-code collaboration but deploy to Heroku. This is quite common and well supported. Simply develop and push to github during your development workflow with `git push origin master` (here, the github remote is your `origin`).

When you want to deploy to Heroku you would then do a `git push heroku master` (here, the heroku repo is labeled as the `heroku` remote).

The fact that there are two git remotes for the same project is not a problem and is, in fact, well-optimized due to git's distributed nature. Using Heroku to develop a backing API or web app for your mobile apps does not mean you can't use GitHub for your source control.

Comment: Ok, I am staying with github. Just to understand and Sorry, have not started using heroku yet - so, when you push to heroku you go live with a page etc. could you not push to a branche? But then again, if the source code is for something different than the site(heroku) then it does not make sense right.

Comment: You could push to a branch on heroku, but a deploy will only happen when a push goes to `master`.